# iPhone 3GS headphone sound is crackly

Tags: iphone, headphones

I have a problem with the sound from the headphone jack on my iPhone 3GS. Sound from the speaker is fine, but the sound from the headphone jack (on any headphones) is distorted at normal volumes. If I turn the volume down to about halfway then the distortion vanishes but the volume becomes barely audible.

I've just replaced the headphone jack with a brand new assembly, so it's not a problem with jack itself.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Curious if the crackling was there before you swapped the jack or came with or after that operation.

Comment: have you tried new headphones?

Comment: The crackling was the reason I swapped the headphone jack. When I bought the phone everything worked fine, but at some point the headphones started crackling.

Comment: I've tried many different sets of headphones, and all suffer the same problem, so I'm pretty sure it's the phone that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna say if you take it to Apple, they will confirm the audio processing chip on the mobo has maybe become faulty. Seen this before, took it to Apple, the chip responsible for audio processing had fried itself (not sure how). They replaced my iPhone.